# How can I draw a double coordinate system with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw this double coordinate system. 
[image]
At maximum I can draw this (on the code)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{cqcqcq}{rgb}{0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882,0.7529411764705882}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [color=cqcqcq,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt, xstep=2.0cm,ystep=2.0cm] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[->,color=black] (-0.0,0.0) -- (11
,0.0);
\foreach \x in {0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,10.0}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\draw[->,color=black] (0.0,-7.111454243646196) -- (0.0,11.88836233932886);
\foreach \y in {0,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,10.0}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
\clip(-7.592067226089411,-7.111454243646196) rectangle (29.694262245619367,11.88836233932886);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you borrowed the code from somewhere, please remember to attribute it....

Comment: I am guessing that that code was generated by some s/w. IMHO, you would be much better of scrapping that code and starting from scratch. That way not only will you be able to simplify the code considerably but you'll also learn and then be able to modify it easily.

Comment: @PeterGrill That was my initial guess. But why not draw something closer? At least with the numbers? Even so, you're probably right. Certainly somebody generated it using s/w.

Answer (score 4):

Something to start with.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,5);
\draw [->] (0,0)--(6.5,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,0)--(0,5.5) node[above left] {$y$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
    \draw (\i,.3)--++(-90:6mm) node[below]{\i};
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
    \draw (.3,\i)--++(180:6mm) node[left]{\i};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {0};

\begin{scope}[shift={(3,2)},draw=purple, text=purple]
\draw [->] (0,0)--(3.5,0) node[below right] {$x'$};
\draw [->] (0,0)--(0,4.5) node[above left] {$y'$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
    \draw (\i,.3)--++(-90:6mm) node[below]{\i};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \draw (.3,\i)--++(180:6mm) node[left]{\i};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {0};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]